# "Error found when loading /etc/profile" when booting up

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, xrandr

I've been getting this error when booting up recently.

**Error found when loading /etc/profile**

**xrandr: cannot find output DP-1**

I tried searching through /etc/profile but i couldn't find a single reference to DP-1 or anything related to monitors in there.
As you can see in the xrandr i pasted bellow, i have a dual monitor setup where the second monitor is referenced by DVI-1. Maybe this has something to do with this? Also, this error has not influenced my daily use of my computer, after this error message the computer boots up fine and the monitors work like normal.

And i  think it is needed to say that since i installed Ubuntu for the first time last week i have been messing with xrandr configs. The second monitor, DVI-1, had the wrong resolution when i first booted up Ubuntu. I had to addmode 1280x720, and to make it permanent i altered the .profile file in the home directory (not /etc/profile). Since then i have been getting this error.

What should i do? Maybe append something to /etc/profile? If so, what?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
timm@lftimm-pc:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected 1280x720+0+204 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1280x720_60.00  59.86* 
  1680x1000_60.00 (0x6ce) 139.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  62.17KHz
        v: height 1000 start 1003 end 1013 total 1038           clock  59.89Hz
```

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for reminding me, i have already edited my post. I am running the latest LTS release.

Comment: Remember that `/etc/profile` may source other files in `/etc/profile.d/` so check those as well